# My flashlight works the first time, force closes the next

Tags: java, android

I have a torch class, when I use `ledon()` my flashlight turns on.
When I use `ledoff()` it turns off. **But** if i try to turn it back on again, I get a force close.
And then it turns on again if I try.

What is the reason for the force close?

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;

import static android.hardware.Camera.*;

/**
* Created by tyler on 8/13/13.
*/
public class Torch {
    private static final String TAG = "Light";
    private static Camera mCamera;
    private static Camera.Parameters mParameters;

    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static void ledon()
    {
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        mParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
        Log.d(TAG, "Turn On");
    }

    public static void ledoff(MainActivity activity) {       
        String flashMode = mParameters.getFlashMode();

        if (Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF.equals(flashMode)) {
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        }

        mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        mParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
        Log.d(TAG, "Turn Off");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is my updated code, it turns off and on all I want, but when I turn it on and then on again, it Force Closes. Logcat below code.

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;

/**
* Created by tyler on 8/13/13.
*/
public class Torch {

private static final String TAG =  "Light";
private static Camera mCamera;
private static Camera.Parameters mParameters;
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = mCamera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return c;

}


public static void ledon() {

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        String flashMode = mParameters.getFlashMode();
            if (! flashMode.equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
            mParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
            Log.d(TAG, "Turn On"); 
        }
    }
public static void ledoff() {
        String flashMode = mParameters.getFlashMode();
            if (! flashMode.equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
            mParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
            mCamera.release();
            Log.d(TAG, "Turn Off");
        }

    }
}
```

Logcat:

08-15 12:01:10.502  25951-25951/com.tyler.myapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4170f898)
08-15 12:01:10.522  25951-25951/com.tyler.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.tyler.myapp.Torch.ledon(Torch.java:28)

Comment: did you got anything on logcat? It would be helpful to understand the cause.

Comment: Can u update your question with codes in `open();` method ?

Comment: The golden rule of Android debugging: If your app closes, please post a logcat copy :)

Comment: and the double camera import.. weird stuff going on. definitely need a logcat.

Comment: Will post log cat tomorrow, my bad. And I see a few answers that might work so I'll update with that too.

Comment: Also, I was trying random things that eclipse suggested... I agree weird stuff. It's what happens when I'm at a loss.

Comment: Logcat just says nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure as I didn't check it but I think because you are updating the mParameters in the ledOff.

try this method

```
public static void ledSwitch() {

            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            String flashMode = mParameters.getFlashMode();
            if (Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF.equals(flashMode)) {
                mParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                Log.d(TAG, "Turn On");  
            } else {
                mCamera.release()
                mParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                Log.d(TAG, "Turn Off");
            }
}
```

this method will check if it's on will make it off, if it's off will make it on.

I took .release() from Levente Kurusa :D

**updated --**

try this, as an HTC user I use different way of camera as I read, so I searched the internet for you.

```
public static Camera mCameraDevice;
private static List<String> flashModes; 
private static String currentFlashMode; 

Camera.Parameters param = mCameraDevice.getParameters();
flashModes = param.getSupportedFlashModes();

if (flashModes != null) {
    currentFlashMode = param.getFlashMode();

    if (currentFlashMode.equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
       currentFlashMode = Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON;
    }
    else {
       currentFlashMode = Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF;
    }

    param.setFlashMode(currentFlashMode);
    mCameraDevice.setParameters(param);
}
```

&& don't forget to use these permissions

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: Nicely incorporating my answer to yours :)

Comment: No, it doesn't bother me, I just felt happy that someone did that actually:D

Answer (score 3):

Without your logcat, nobody can say for sure what is your problem, but I suspect something. After calling `ledon` you should call `mCamera.release()` to tell the android system that you are no longer using the Camera. If you don't call this, on the next call to `ledon`, you try to allocate a new `Camera` object, but the Camera with id=0 is used by an application, which is YOUR application, and therefore it throws a `RuntimeException`. You catch it, and then set the `mCamera` to `null` and then later reference `mCamera`, hence the `NullPointerException` which I suspect to be the cause.

Comment: Would you please accept the answer? (I suppose it worked for you)